# Echo array row as a variable sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a problem that I think i understand the issue but I'm stuck for a resolution.

I have a sql query running in PHP as follows:

```
$sql = "select COUNT(*) From dbo
Where dbo.table.STATUS < 4";

$Backlog = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if( $Backlog === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $Row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $Backlog, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
      echo $Row[0];
}
```

My connection to the source is fine and if I put this out via a basic PHP page I get the result of the query printed on the page.

However, I'm trying to call $Backlog on a different page with some CSS formatting:

```
<?php echo "<div class =second_row_label>Incident Back Log</div><div class =top_num>".$Backlog."</div></div></a>"; ?>
```

And it's here I'm getting the Resource ID #x error.

From scanning the various pages I believe $Backlog is my resource so the question is, how can I call the result as the variable $Backlog on the second sheet?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display there, one of the values that you retrieved from the database? If so, which one?

Comment: I'm doing a count from the DB and I want to display the value in the second page. calling the value from the first page. In effect I want the entire initial query and thus result to be the variable $Backlog so when I call the result on the second page it outputs the values from the DB query in the initial page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think sessions will solve your problem.

Store your values to [$_SESSION variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). You can then use those $_SESSION variable on any page that includes session_start()

Comment: Worked like a charm once I worked out where to put the $_SESSION syntax. Thanks!